# The solution of a partial differential equation( I can't work out the equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $ y=f(x,t) $ and $F(x,y,t)=0  $  The function is determined
$t=t(x,y)$ what is $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$
This is original question.

Comment: I have corrected it, now it's exactly the same as the answer.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is given? And what you want to prove. In sentences. At present the first line is just a jumble of symbols.

Comment: Maybe it should be dx here, I have fixed, I want to know what is $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: What is the equation to be solved ???

Comment: alright, forget them, this is original question, I detele my answers steps, thanks.

Comment: @appleMusic that's cheating, now you've made it easier! :'D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $F(x,y,t)=0$ determines $t$ as a function of $(x,y)$, and then $y=f(x,t)$ determines $y$ as a function of $x$. We are asked to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Differentiating we have
$$
F_x dx+ F_y dy +F_t dt=0 \tag{1}
$$ and
$$
dy= f_x dx+ f_t dt \tag{2}
$$
where I have written $F_x$ for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and so on.

From (1) we express $dt$ in terms of $dx,dy$ and substitute this into (2) getting
$$
dy= f_x dx + f_t \big(F_x dx +F_y dy\big)\frac{-1}{F_t}
$$
or
$$
(1+f_t \frac{F_y}{F_t})dy
=
(f_x-f_t \frac{F_x}{F_t})dx 
$$
so that finally
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}
=
\frac{f_x-f_t \frac{F_x}{F_t}}{1+f_t \frac{F_y}{F_t}}.
$$

Comment: sincerely thanks

Answer (score 1):

This form is called a [Total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative).
$\require{cancel}$
Given $$dy=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt$$

$$dy=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial y}dy\right)$$

$$dy=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \dfrac{\partial f}{\cancel{\partial t}}\dfrac{\cancel{\partial t}}{\partial x}dx + \dfrac{\partial f}{\cancel{\partial t}}\dfrac{\cancel{\partial t}}{\partial y}dy$$

$$dy=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

$$dy=2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

$$dy\left(1-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx$$

$$dy=2\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx}{1-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}}$$

$$dy=2\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx}{\dfrac{\partial y-\partial f}{\partial y}}$$

$$dy=2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx\cdot\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial y-\partial f}$$

From an 'engineering' point of view simply divide $dy$ with $dx$.

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial y-\partial f}$$

Of course what you write down has to make sense mathematically. So you can only derive this way if $t$ depends on $x$.

Comment: Surely we're told that $t=t(x,y)$ so that you don't get a total derivative of $t$ w.r.t $x$, you need to put $dt=t_x dx+ t_y dy$ and then take the $dy$'s all to one side before proceeding?

Comment: @ancientmathematician, that's actually a good catch!

Comment: @ancientmathematician please tell me if the edit made sense to you

Comment: I think the question is not clearly formulated.Personally I don't think you can cancel the partials w.r.t $t$ as you do. And your answer doesn't seem to involve $F$ - until the OP makes clear exactly what's given it's hard to go further.